# Single app with built-in marketplace versus multiple apps on google play

Tags: android, google-play, marketplace

We are designing/developing a learning application for kids (3+). We are considering options to have one solid app with built-in marketplace of learnings programs supporting also different languages, screen types - content will be downloaded/purchased separately.
The another option is to make multiple build and upload as different applications for each learning program.
How will google play market will like the last approach? Is it possible to have different google play publications for each learning program?

Comment: Yes, It will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your apps do not fall under the "Spam and Placement in the Store" policy listet [here](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) you should be fine. Personally I have never heard of someone who had his app removed because of this policy, this should really only happen if the app (and it's content) is exactly identical.

Edit: This of course means that you can have different publications for each learning program.